# Samsung Smart TV Creating app using AppsFramevork

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I try to create application using tutorial on Samsung Dev foum (https://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00001/index.html).
But it doesn't work on emulator (no one alert are shown in emulator console and shown black screen).
Can you give me working example of Samsung app with af?

Comment: For example, i create new project. In app folder create **init.js** and define onStart function with alert smth. In **index.html** load **$WIDGET_MANAGER/Common/af/2.0.0./loader.js**. And no alert at all in the emulator.

Comment: alert in emulator and samsung smart tv is different than web browser.
Look at the console window below emulator, the alert is like console.log in common web apps

Comment: I know, i saw alert directly from index.html, from onStart nothing happens. There is no lines about loading init.js, why?